# Leaving a voice message by typing a text

Tags: android, voicemail

When calling a phone number one sometime falls on a voice mail. I sometimes prefer to leave text messages than voice mail messages, but some phone numbers don't accept text messages.

I am looking for an Android program that can take a written text as input and takes care of leaving a message on the voicemail through text-to-speech conversion. Free of charge. Less preferable but still OK: web service or Windows/Linux program. I'm mostly interested in the United States (i.e. both sender and recipient in the United States).

---

Some carriers offer this service, but it is not free:

[Spring](http://support.sprint.com/support/article/Send-a-text-message-to-a-landline/case-cx832318-20090918-173806#!/):

> Sending a text message to a landline is just like sending a standard text message. Just create a text message from your Sprint phone and address it to a 10-digit phone number. Your text is converted to a voice message, which is automatically read to the recipient when he or she answers the phone. If the recipient does not answer the phone, your text message is stored as a voicemail, provided the recipient has voicemail service on their landline phone. Your recipient can also reply to your message. Effective July 1, 2014, each text message to a landline will cost **$0.25**. Customers will be required to opt-in before being charged for sending a text to landline.

Some web services offer this service, but I haven't found any free one:

[MessageBird](https://www.messagebird.com/en-us/text-to-speech):

> Easily integrate Text to Speech messages into your app, CRM software or website and send a voice message to any phone in the world, landline or mobile. 1000 SMS cost $17. Web interface or API.

Comment: Do you want it to text if the number accepts texts and perform text-to-speech otherwise?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Ideally yes but is it possible to test whether the recipient can receive a text?

Comment: That would be my next question!  ;)

Comment: Many phone carriers (all the major ones in the US, as far as I know) offer this as a service to allow sending text messages to landline phones. However, I don't know any details about it - only that it exists.

Comment: Do you need a separate program to do this? I think many phone companies have such service already. I know Verizon (in the US) does, if you try to send a text message to a landline (for a small fee of course). The offer is in a reply to the original text message.

Comment: @MosheKatz Thanks, good point, I added one example in the question.

Comment: @user3169 Yes ideally I prefer to avoid carrier-dependent solutions. It looks like there exist quite a few solutions, so to narrow the question I have added the requirement needs to be free. If not, please just mention it as a comment or in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) has support for [text messaging](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+text). Plug-ins [capable of voice synthesis](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Text-to-Speech+%28TTS%29) are available.

Admittedly, this solution will probably take some time to set up.